# Why does PowerShell command work from prompt but not when using -Command switch?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I open Windows PowerShell and start by setting up a test directory.

```
PS C:> md Sample && cd Sample
```

This is an important step. My testing has shown the command I want to use, that opens the properties dialog, does not work for all directories.

Then, I issue the command I am working on:

```
PS C:\Sample> (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).NameSpace((Get-Location).Path).Self.InvokeVerb('Properties')
```

As expected, the folder properties dialog of the current directory is opened.

[image: Windows folder properties of directory C:\Sample]

Now I open cmd and try to run the same call:

```
C:\Sample> PowerShell.exe -Command "& {(New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).NameSpace((Get-Location).Path).Self.InvokeVerb('Properties')}"
```

The call succeeds (errorlevel is zero), but the dialog box *does not* open.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Replace `"Properties"` with `'Properties'`, or replace it with `""""Properties""""`.

Comment: Must the script be ran as Adminstrator?

Comment: ```%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "(New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).NameSpace((Get-Location).Path).Self.InvokeVerb(\"Properties\")"```, or as already advised ```%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "(New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).NameSpace((Get-Location).Path).Self.InvokeVerb('Properties')"```.

Comment: Curiously, the original script does not work for me in some folders (throws COM errors about missing DLLs).

Comment: @Compo this does not seem to work for me on Windows 11.

Comment: Replacing the quotes does not work. I can run `PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -Command "& {echo 'Properties'}"` and the process echoes back "Properties", so I believe it's not a simple quotation escape problem.

Comment: TBF, my comment was for fixing your quotes in the command you provided as working in a Windows PowerShell command window. However, copying that command, as is, into a Windows PowerShell window on a Windows 11 machine does nothing for me either!

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you executing the your original command in?  I'm having no joy in 5.1, but 7.x.x works.  If it is 7.x.x, then you probably need to change your cmd command from `PowerShell.exe -Command "<PSCode>"` to `PWSH.exe -Command "<PSCode>"`.

Comment: It's not a Windows 11 vs 10 things, and it's not a PowerShell version thing. It appears the command doesn't work from some folders. If you create "C:\Sample", change directories into that folder and then run the command it will work.

Comment: @brad-tot, OK, that is weird behavior.  If, while in either PS 5.1 or 7.4.1 prompt, I try running it from my user profile folder, nothing happens.  But if I change to "C:\Sample", "C:\Temp" or "C:\Temp\CS", it works!  I decided to replace `(Get-Location).Path` with the actual path, such as `'C:\Temp'` and it works, but still fails when I try the path of my user profile.  I thought maybe it is the call operator in the CMD command, so in ps7 prompt I tried `& {(New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).NameSpace('C:\Temp').Self.InvokeVerb('Properties')}`, this works!

Answer (score 0):

The call does succeed, but the lifespan of the dialog box is tied to the lifespan of the PowerShell process that started it.

This can be demonstrated within cmd by adding a sleep to the end of the script block:

```
C:\Sample>PowerShell.exe -Command "& {(New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).NameSpace((Get-Location).Path).Self.InvokeVerb('Properties');Start-Sleep -Seconds 2.0}"
```

The dialog box appears for two seconds and then disappears when the PowerShell process exits.

Alternatively, it is possible to use the `-NoExit` flag instead:

```
C:\Sample>PowerShell.exe -NoExit -Command "& {(New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).NameSpace((Get-Location).Path).Self.InvokeVerb('Properties')}"
```

This, of course, leaves PowerShell running within cmd until manually exited.

```
PS C:\Sample> exit
```

The exit call will close the dialog if it is still open.

To summarize the answer to my original question: the command works the same at both the prompt and when using a script block with `PowerShell.exe -Command`. The dialog doesn't have a chance to display in the latter case, however, unless the PowerShell process is kept open.

For me, neither `-NoExit` nor `Start-Sleep` is an acceptable workaround. I fear I will soon be iterating processes and/or windows to figure out how to wait on the user to close that properties dialog. Funny how a one-liner can turn so complicated, no?